# Special Characters on program

Tags: x86, tasm

This is my first time here.

My friend told me about this forum if I have some questions about programming.

So here is my program. My problem is that there are special characters printed too.

How will I remove this?

```
.model small
.stack
.data
   var db "Welcome to Assembly Language$"
.code

clear proc near

   mov ah, 6
   mov bh, 2h
   mov cx, 0
   mov dx, 184fh
   int 10h
   ret

   clear endp


cursor proc near

   mov ah, 2
   mov bh, 0
   mov dh, 10
   mov dl, 14
   int 10h
   ret
   cursor endp

 start:

   body proc near
   call clear
   call cursor

   mov ah, 9
   mov dx, offset var
   int 21h
   mov ah, 4ch
   int 21h

  body endp

 end start
```

How can I remove the Special Characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a segment problem: when you use the the `.data` directive, the data are placed in a segment accessed via the `DS` register while the `.code` directive puts the assembled code into segment accessed via `CS` register.

With small memory model, all data, code and stack memory are merged into a single segment, but the programmer has the responsability to initialize the segment registers by himself.

You see weird characters because the data are accessed by the `int 21h` interruption via `DS:DX` but has `DS` points to a wrong segment number you see garbage before your data. You just need to fix `DS` to avoid the garbage output.

Add this at the begining of your `body` proc:

```
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
```

We need to use `AX` as intermediate value because we cannot `mov DS:@data`

This [16 bit asm reference](http://physinfo.ulb.ac.be/cit_courseware/asm/asm_5.htm) can help.